# Find both pattern and position of multiple regex matches in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

This should be an easy question but I can't find anything about it.

Given a regular expression in Ruby, for every match I need to retrieve the matched patterns `$1`, `$2`, but I also need the matching position.

I know that the `=~` operator gives me the position of the first match, while `string.scan(/regex/)` gives me all matching patterns. If possible I need to have both results in the same step.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[MatchData](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/MatchData.html)

```
string.scan(regex) do
  $1           # Pattern at first position
  $2           # Pattern at second position
  $~.offset(1) # Starting and ending position of $1
  $~.offset(2) # Starting and ending position of $2
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access match data within scan like this:

```
"abcdefghij".scan(/\w/) {p $~}
```