# Find the position of each capture group in a string

Tags: ruby, regex

I found how to get the offset of a match in a string, the starting position of each matches... But I can't find a easy way to find the position in a string of the begining a capture group.

```
string.scan(regex) do |match|
    positions << Regexp.last_match.offset(0)[1]
end
```

This code only give me the begining position of each match in the string. I would

Maybe I'm a bad googler, in that case I'm sorry. In advance, thank you for your help.

**Edit 3: Duplicata** It seems my question is a duplicata of ["Find both pattern and position of multiple regex matches in Ruby"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589460/find-both-pattern-and-position-of-multiple-regex-matches-in-ruby?lq=1). I saw this question before asking but I didn't understood that I found what I was looking for. My mistake. But I think the answer I got here is less "arcanic" than the other. Thank you.

**Edit 1:**

I work with DNA sequence. For example, I have this string and this regex :

```
string = "ggtgtcaactatccgccgcgaagcacgtaacgtctctcttgacaccgaatcataggtgcgacagt"
regex = /cg(.)a(.)/
```

I want to know each position of captured characters. So :

```
[20, 22, 27, 29, 47, 49]
```

**Edit 2: Solution** 
Thanks to @7stud

```
string = "ggtgtcaactatccgccgcgaagcacgtaacgtctctcttgacaccgaatcataggtgcgacagt"
regex = /cg(.)a(.)/
positions = Array.new
string.scan(regex) do
  md = Regexp.last_match
  md.captures.each_with_index { |capture, i|
      positions << md.begin(i + 1)
  }
end
p positions.to_a
```

Comment: `m = "aabbccdd".match /(..)..(..)../ puts m.begin 1 puts m.begin 2`

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how many times the regex will match. I would like to find all the groups of all matches. I think I will use tour code and write a method to repeat the process and simulate the `scan`behaviour.

Comment: `s.scan(/(..)..(..)../).flatten.map { |match| [match, s.index(match)] }`

Comment: I had the same question a couple days ago.  The answers to the question I just linked had surprised me.  Caveat: if you are working with very large data, and must consider run time, look into exploring the `Benchmark` object.

Comment: @NewAlexandria I'm not working with large data this time but I will think about Benchmark if I have to. I had already saw this response but I don't know why, I didn't like it...

Comment: Well, 'speaking as a librarian', it is a duplicate. No worries though. If you thought the question was different then you would have done best to reference the other but indicate why that was not a sufficient solution. I imagine you found the extreme ruby idioms there too arcane?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was my first question here. I understand very the problem of the duplicate, I will edit to add the link and explanation. And yes, there was not enough text around the code to a good comprehension in the response linked. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't find a easy way to find the position in a string of the begining a capture group.

Like this:

```
str = 'aa123bb456'

str.scan(/(.)(.)(\d+)/) do 
  md = Regexp.last_match
  p md.offset(1)
  p md.offset(2)
  p md.offset(3)
  puts '-' * 20
end



--output:--
[0, 1]
[1, 2]
[2, 5]
--------------------
[5, 6]
[6, 7]
[7, 10]
```

In the first match, the beginning of the capture groups in the string are 0, 1, 2, and for the second match the beginning of the capture groups are 5, 6, 7.

Alternatively, if you only want the start of each capture, as hwnd demonstrated, you can do this:

```
str = 'aa123bb456'

str.scan(/(.)(.)(\d+)/) do 
  md = Regexp.last_match
  p md.begin(1)
  p md.begin(2)
  p md.begin(3)
  puts '-' * 20
end


--output:--
0
1
2
--------------------
5
6
7
--------------------
```

> Yes, but I don't know how many times the regex will match

How is that relevant?

Response to edit:

```
str = "ggtgtcaactatccgccgcgaagcacgtaacgtctctcttgacaccgaatcataggtgcgacagt"
regex = /cg(.)a(.)/

results = []

str.scan(regex) do 
  md = Regexp.last_match
  results << md.begin(1) << md.begin(2)
end

p results

--output:--
[20, 22, 27, 29, 47, 49]
```

Comment: Yes ! Thank you very much @7stud ! I saw almost the same thing in an another place but I didn't understand that it could make the job...

Comment: Yes, I add a loop be cause I don't know how many group I will have and it's good !